# how to exit from current shell and save the variable using perl

Tags: bash, perl, variables, exit

I have run this script, but it wont exit from current shell (i.e. bash). then it wont run the command after it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$ENV{MYVAR}="test";
exec 'bash','-f';
print "End.\n";
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you are attempting to accomplish. What is the end goal you want to reach?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perldoc -f exec

   exec LIST
   exec PROGRAM LIST
           The "exec" function executes a system command and never
           returns; use "system" instead of "exec" if you want it to
           return.
```

Comment: tq @hymie I try to use "system" instead of "exec" also didn't work...same thing happen..it wont come out from bash shell

Comment: It does after you type "exit" at the prompt of the interactive Bash shell you started from Perl.